# Reading multiple lists

Tags: c++, list

I'm working on a project where I need to read multiple lists from a text file. As well as reading them, it reports some calculations based on the ints read in. The file reading ends at a sentinel given at the beginning of a list.

The list I am using to test is:

```
9999  //sent value
636.9 // number to be ignored
First
4
8
15
16
23
42
Second
0.0
9999
```

The problem I am having is that, my code reads through and stores the data of the first list correctly, but when the loop goes through again it doesn't read the second list.

My main loop is:

```
infile >> sent;
infile >> inX;

while (!infile.fail())
{
    inX = 0;
    while (inX != sent)
    {
        int dSize = 0;
        storeNames(listNames, infile);
        ReadData(theData, infile);
        cout << listNames[count] << endl;
        cout << "Size is\t\t\t" << theData.size() << endl;
        if (theData.size() >= 1)
        {
            ComputeStats(theData, meanValue, secondHigh);
            DisplayStats(meanValue, secondHigh);
            dSize = theData.size();
            inX = theData[dSize - 1];
        }

        theData.clear();
        count++;
    }
}
```

The read data function is:

```
void ReadData(vector<int>& theData, ifstream& in)
{
    if (in.is_open())
    {
        int number;
        while (in >> number)
        {
            theData.push_back(number);

        }
    }
}
```

and finally the storeNames function is:

```
void storeNames(vector<string>& listNames, ifstream& in)
{
    string name;
    in >> name;
    listNames.push_back(name);
}
```

Thank you very much in advance for the help!

Comment: Seems like an issue with your input files. Best thing to do would be step through with a debugger.

Comment: Can you show your input file?

Comment: I've gone through with the debugger, here is the input file.                9999
636.9
First
4
8
15
16
23
42
Second
0.0
9999

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> while (in >> number)

Considering the code above, do you restore the stream state after it failed? readData will consume everything, after which the state of the stream need to be restored, and seekg moved back if you want to read again.

Restoring istream state can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681555/resetting-the-end-of-file-state-of-a-ifstream-object-in-c)

Whether you need to move seekg depends on whether you want to consume the same data again, else you might want to move the stream pointer to the next data section.

Comment: I do not think I do. How would I go about doing that?