# Pass ifstream object by reference to multiple functions

Tags: c++11, file-io, ifstream

I'd like to pass the same ifstream reference to multiple functions as shown below. But I noticed that the infile variable becomes null after the call `f1( infile );`

```
void f1(istream& infile)
{
    char c = file.get();
}

void f2(istream& infile)
{
    char c = file.get();
    // other read operations
}

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("content.txt",std::ios_base::in);
    if ( infile.good() )
    {
        if (!infile)
        {
            cout << "file not open for f1\n";
        }
        f1( infile );
        if (!infile)
        {
            cout << "file not open for f2n";
        }
        f2( infile );
    }
    infile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm wondering how to go about it if I don't want to create another ifstream variable? Thank you

Comment: Missing some braces on the first `if` ?  Your indentation and the compiler's parse don't match as written.

Comment: In your troubleshooting code, I'd get rid of the check on `is_open()` completely, as your other error-reporting code will detect it.

Comment: I added the edits to make the fixes in the code above. Also added an answer that works for me following the insight suggested by @BenVoigt

Answer (score 0):

> the `infile` variable becomes null

No, it doesn't.  But it does become "failed".  The `!` operator on a stream is checking its failbit, not whether it is "null".

The reason it fails is that you are trying to output to an input-only stream.  In fact, this code shouldn't even compile....

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I edited the main post to do some read operations. The code above is a simplified version of my original task, so missed the output op from a template I copied

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @BenVoigt, the second `!` operator check was failing as the eof bit was set after the first read operation.
The fix is below. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7681612))

```
infile.clear(); // clears fail and eof bits
infile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg); // move pointer back to start
```

Comment: ... if indeed the second function expects to start from the top of the file.  Unfortunately your question didn't give any indication of that.